# Add a Cert to winrm certMapping Table

Tags: powershell, winrm

I want to add my self signed certificate to the winrm certMapping table. For this I try this command:

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=IP:172.16.17.51+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="TestWIN-BUERJK3TB3E";CertificateThumbprint="02cb8ba899cd9631c9afc32c0e797aca8acc562f"}
```

But the Command gives me an error:

```
Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
```

I typed "winrm -?" but it doesnt helped me. So what did I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That `CertificateThumbprint` value is not valid, it's always the hex-encoded signature hash of the certificate

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I typed a random code. I was to lazy to type the full code. I corrected the CertificateThumbprint value with the right code.